# Как сравнить на "С" числа и заменить меньшее?

Tags: c

Как заменить меньшее из значений А и В на 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя условный оператор

```
if (a < b) a = 3; else b = 3;
```

Используя тернарный оператор

```
(a < b) ? (a = 3) : (b = 3)
```

Используя логические приоритеры

```
(a < b) && (a = 3) || (a > b) && (b = 3)
```

Comment: 1. Не рассмотрен случай a==b. Что тогда делать? Или ничего, или установить оба числа в 3, или произвольное число заменить на 3?

2. Логические приоритеты - хорошо, но следует отметить, что они работают только, если компилятор не высчитывает все выражение целиком, а оптимизирует и считает только до того места, где становится ясно какое значение у всего выражения.

Comment: Еще вариант:
<preint *p;
p = (a < b) ? &a : &b;
*p = 3;</pre>

Comment: Если в сравнение в стогом смысле, то видимо так


    if (a < b) a = 3;
    if (b < a) b = 3;

Answer (score 1):

Сравнить в операторе ***if()*** ,заменить (присвоить переменной новое значение) операцией **=** .